# How to use the space for \def argument's separator

Tags: macros

Assume there is a line including some single letter like A, b, C, etc. and the letters separate by only one white space, which ASCII code is 32, say,

```
D B g A
```

I want the content for a \def's arguments, For example,

```
\def\mydef#1 #2 #3 #4{\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}
```

the

```
\mydef{D B g A}
```

output bold D, italic B, smallcap g, and slanted A. Other situations export a warning message. Note: the \r\n (ASCII code 13) or \n (ASCII code 10) be seen as ending of \mydef.

Comment: Actually, neither `\r\n` nor `\n` is what your `\mydef` sees, since TeX converts all the various system-dependent newline indicators into its internal one `^^M` (which I believe is the same ASCII code as `\n`, however).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mydef#1 #2 #3 #4{\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}
\def\myDef#1{\expandafter\myDefi#1}
\def\myDefi#1 #2 #3 #4{\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}
\begin{document}
\mydef A B C D foo

\myDef{A B C D} foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the `\expandafter` for?  The `#1` will be "expanded" before `\myDefi` anyway, by the macro substitution rules, so it looks like you want to expand argument `#1` of `\myDefi` but not the others.

Comment: in this case it has no meaning, but it doesn't hurt and I use it by default, because I do not really know what arguments users may have in mind.

Answer (score 10):

`\mydef{D B g A}` is reading `{D B g A}` as first argument because of the `{ }`.
It then looks for the `#2 #3 #4` part afterwards and raises an error if there is no such input. You need to either write directly `\mydef D B G A` or use a second macro like that inside `\mydef`, which is more often used.

```
\def\mydef#1{\mydefb#1}
\def\mydefb#1 #2 #3 #4{\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}
```

You might want to add a trailing space to ensure that all input of `\mydef` is processed by `\mydefb`, otherwise if the last part is more than one letter the rest is just typeset after `\mydefb`:

```
\def\mydef#1{\mydefb#1 }
\def\mydefb#1 #2 #3 #4 {\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}
```

Comment: Thanks your detailed explain. But Herbert is earier so I get tick to him. Too hard do the choice!