# Distinguish space (ASCII 32) and return (ASCII 13) in \def's arguments

Tags: macros

A related question can [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16811/how-to-use-the-space-for-def-arguments-seperator). I want the \mydef behavior is

```
\mydef{a b c d}
```

get a correct export but

```
\mydef{a b
 c d}
```

or

```
\mydef{a b c d
}
```

get a incorrect export (like a warning message).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "correct export"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, the following  does what you ask for, it provokes an errro at compilation time:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mydef{\catcode13=15\relax\mydefi}

\def\mydefi#1{\catcode13=5\relax\mydefii#1}

\def\mydefii#1 #2 #3 #4{%
\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}

\begin{document}
\mydef{A B C D} foo

\mydef{a b c d}

%% \mydef{a b
%%  c d}

%% or

\mydef{a b c d
}

\end{document}
```

The commented-out lines would also provoke an error. If you just want some kind of warning, the following can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifwarn
\makeatletter

\def\mydef{\catcode13=\active\begingroup\lccode`\~=13\relax
     \lowercase{\endgroup\let~\stop}\mydefi}

\def\myparse #1{\ifnot@nil{#1}{\ifx #1\stop\warntrue\fi\myparse}}

\def\mydefi#1{\catcode13=5\myparse #1\@nil
      \ifwarn ERROR IN TEX SOURCE\warnfalse\else\mydefii#1\fi}

\def\mydefii#1 #2 #3 #4{%
\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mydef{A B C D} foo
\mydef{a b
 c d}
\mydef{a b c d}

\mydef{a b
 c d}

\mydef{a b
 c 
 d}

\mydef{A B C D} foo

\mydef{a b c d
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Setting the catcode of `^^M` (ASCII 13) to 15 (invalid character) is a very bad idea.

Comment: @egreg: ?? the question asked to set up things in order to create errors, this is what I do! of course, this just stops the compilation as soon as a `\mydef` is found which has an end-of-line in its argument. I thought this was precisely what was asked for. On the other hand, the catcode is reset when the argument of `\mydef` satisfies (my reading of) Stufazi's question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a second possibility. The original question not being very precise I don't know if this will fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mydef#1{\expandafter\mydefi#1}
\def\mydefi#1 #2 #3 #4{\textbf{#1}\textit{#2}\textsc{#3}\textsl{#4}}
\begin{document}
\mydef{A B C D} foo

\mydef{a b c d}

\mydef{a b
 c d}

or

\mydef{a b c d
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why I run the code without any error? Is it possible my editor do some transformation to return and space in silence?

Comment: @Stufazi: without a complete minimal example I can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, the second and third one should fail with a warning message. Yours does not.